# Inserting values into 2D Python list using indexing

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, 2d

I am trying to insert values, one at at time, from several python lists of lists (i.e. 2D lists) into another 2D list. (I know numpy is better at this, but I am trying to compare the performance of lists to numpy, so please don't just suggest numpy.) I want to insert the values at specific locations, hence the indexing on the left hand side.

resampled_pix_spot_list is a 240 by 240 list of lists, and pix_spot_list is a 225 by 225 list of lists.

The error I am getting, from the final four lines in the example, is "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable". I get that pix_prod_bl[0][0], for example, is a float, but I don't understand why I can't insert it into a particular set of indices in resampled_pix_spot_list.

Edit 1- added minimal working example.

Edit 2- in adding the working example, I found that I accidentally had the line commented where I convert the lists back to numpy, and somehow I misinterpreted the Spyder console about where the error was originating. Anyway it works now, thank you very much for the quick feedback. I guess I'll leave this here in case it's helpful to anyone else.

Edit 3- pix_spot_values is an array of data, so just a random array of floats between 0 and 1 will suffice.

```
xc=57
yc=189     
rebin=15

# fraction pixel offset requiring interpolation
dx=xc*rebin-int(np.floor(xc*rebin)) # positive value between 0 and 1
dy=yc*rebin-int(np.floor(yc*rebin)) # positive value between 0 and 1

# weights for interpolation
w00=(1-dy)*(1-dx)
w10=dy*(1-dx)
w01=(1-dy)*dx
w11=dy*dx

# now the rest of the offset is an integer shift
dx=int(np.floor(xc*rebin))-int(np.floor(xc))*rebin # positive integer between 0 and 14
dy=int(np.floor(yc*rebin))-int(np.floor(yc))*rebin # positive integer between 0 and 14

def new_pix_spot(w00, w10, w01, w11, pix_spot_list, ny_spot, nx_spot, rebin, dy, dx):
    #first change numpy array to list
    pix_spot_list=pix_spot_values.tolist()

    #preallocate array of zeros
    resampled_pix_spot_list=[[0 for x in range (ny_spot + rebin)] for y in range(nx_spot+rebin)]

    #create 2D lists
    pix_prod_bl = [[x*w00 for x in y] for y in pix_spot_list]#bottom left
    pix_prod_br = [[x*w10 for x in y] for y in pix_spot_list]#bottom right
    pix_prod_tl = [[x*w01 for x in y] for y in pix_spot_list]#top left
    pix_prod_tr = [[x*w11 for x in y] for y in pix_spot_list]#top right

    for i in range (len(pix_spot_list)):
        for j in range (len(pix_spot_list)):

            k=dy + i
            m=dx + j
            n=dy + 1 + i
            p=dx + 1 + i

            resampled_pix_spot_list[k][m] += pix_prod_bl[i][j] #bottom left
            resampled_pix_spot_list[n][m] += pix_prod_br[i][j] #bottom right
            resampled_pix_spot_list[k][p] += pix_prod_tl[i][j] #top left
            resampled_pix_spot_list[n][p] += pix_prod_tr[i][j] #top right


    resampled_pix_spot_values = np.array(resampled_pix_spot_list)

    return resampled_pix_spot_values
```

Comment: `"TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"` means that you're trying to access a float as if it's a list. I.e. `42.42[0]`. Are you sure that you don't overwrite `resampled_pix_spot_list` or `pix_prod_*` with plain floats anywhere?

Comment: Also a minimal working example would be helpful here. What are the values of `dy`, `dx`, `w00`, `pix_spot_list` etc. so we can try rerunning it ourselves?

Comment: After importing numpy, your code runs without error for me, but then I see that the code doesn't do anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Inserting and Replacing

To insert values into a list in Python, you must work with the *list* object (for example, `resampled_pix_spot_list[0]`) rather than the elements within it (`resampled_pix_spot_list[0][0]`, as you tried).

In both Python 2 and 3, you can insert into a list with `your_list.insert(<index>, <element>)` ([list insertion docs here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)).

So to insert a number to the *left* of your chosen coordinate, the code would be:

```
resampled_pix_spot_list[k].insert(m, pix_prod_bl[i][j])
```

If you wanted to *replace* the pixel at that position, you would write:

```
resampled_pix_spot_list[k][m] = pix_prod_bl[i][j]
```

(Notice the `[k]` vs `[k][m]`.) In short:  To insert, talk to the list; to replace, talk to the element.

---

### Pitfalls of Repeated Inserts

Just a tip:  if you're planning on repeatedly inserting values into specific places in a list, try to iterate from the end of the list, backwards.  If you don't, you'll have to adjust your indices, since each `.insert()` call will shift part of your list to the right.

To see what I mean, let's imagine I have the list `[1, 2, 3]` and want to end up with `[1, 88, 2, 99, 3]` via insertions.  The order we insert matters.  Compare the wrong order (iterating forwards):

```
data = [1, 2, 3]
>>> data.insert(1, 88)
>>> print(data)
[1, 88, 2, 3]  # so far so good
>>> data.insert(2, 99)
>>> print(data)
[1, 88, 99, 2, 3]  # oops!  the first insert changed my indices, so index "2" was wrong!
```

with the right order (iterating backwards):

```
data = [1, 2, 3]
>>> data.insert(2, 99)
>>> print(data)
[1, 2, 99, 3]  # so far so good
>>> data.insert(1, 88)
>>> print(data)
[1, 88, 2, 99, 3]  # same insertions + different order = different results!
```

---

### Slices

Some food for thought:  Python 2.7 and 3 both allow you to replace whole "slices" of lists with a very clean syntax, which would also help you avoid "off-by-one" errors ([slice notation docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)).  For example:

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 3]
>>> data[1:2] = [88, data[1], 99]  # safer, shorter, faster, and clearer
>>> print(data)
[1, 88, 2, 99, 3]
```

Working with slices might be a bit more declarative and clear.  Hope this helps!